# Inkscape 1.1 frequently crashes, even on the smallest of occasions

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape 1.1 offers a number of useful new features and also bug fixes, but it seems that stability has suffered or some ugly little thing was overlooked in the rush to release the 1.1 version.

In any case, the program now crashes so often and on the smallest of occasions that it's almost unbearable.

Do I have no choice but to return to the old version?

Answer (score 2):

I thought of reporting the issue to the Inkscape team.

But when [searching for *crash* in the known issues on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/?scope=all&state=opened&search=crash), I often found replies mentioning the *Document Properties dialog* like the following<sup>[*]</sup>

> Hi, do you have the document properties dialog open? If so, can you try closing it to see if it still crashes?

Closing it indeed fixed the frequent crashes for me.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> Source: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/5474